# How do you handle dead links? (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=www.nhforge.org)

Tags: discussion, external-links

It appears that nhforge.org is no longer an official source on hibernate information, and that much of the site is now on http://nhibernate.info/

However, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=www.nhforge.org shows 76 results linking to dead links.

How do you go about fixing the dead links?

Comment: I don't think that SO will handle and fix dead link using cron.... To do that, they need to scan all questions and answers... Then need to identify URLs... Then need to find they are broken or not.... It need lots of server resources.....

Comment: Someone will have to edit them

Comment: "It need lots of resources"

Sure, which is why there is a community, mods, and automated mods. My question is that being someone of low thousands of rep, What's the best approach to start fixing them?

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson I think that you're using too many `...` in your comments. Use `.` instead would work better.

Comment: If you're just fixing the dead-link you might hit reviewers resistance. if you have posts that need more editorial fixes you have a higher chance of success. Make sure to include an extensive edit comment to inform reviewers why you are changing a link. You don't want your edit to be mistaken for adding a spam link.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99228/how-should-we-deal-with-questions-that-have-broken-links) (Meta SE)

Comment: The duplicate flagged question seems to only relevent for true dead links, not links where the replacement url is easily found.